# The three biggest numbers in array

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int s;
    cin>>s;
    int t=3;
    int maxValue,imax[t],maxIndex,arr[s];
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    maxValue=arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
        if(arr[i]>maxValue){
             maxValue=arr[i];
             imax[0] = i;
        }
    }
    maxValue=arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
        if (i == imax[0]) { continue; }
        if(arr[i]>maxValue){
            maxValue=arr[i];
            imax[1] = i;
        }
    }
    maxValue=arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
        if (i == imax[0]) { continue; }
        if (i == imax[1]) { continue; }
        if(arr[i]>maxValue){
            maxValue=arr[i];
            imax[2] = i;
        }
    }
    cout<<"First biggest number:"<<arr[imax[0]]<<"\n";
    cout<<"Second biggest number:"<<arr[imax[1]]<<"\n";
    cout<<"Third biggest number:"<<arr[imax[2]];
    return 0;
}
```

This program must return tree numbers which is biggest in this arraybut , i do not know why when  I introduce as example five numbers (121,34,56,67,545) and the compiler was return 545 and then crash.
Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: `arr[s]` ain't standard C++. Can you not use a `std::vector<int>` instead? Also, how do you handle the case where the top 3 numbers contain duplicates?

Comment: As @Bathsheba said, use `std::vector`. Then look up `std::nth_element`.

Comment: when i start compiler I introduce as example five numbers (121,34,56,67,545) and the compiler was return 545 and then break down

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use it.

Comment: Step through the program line by line in a debugger. It is small enough that this is feasible. Compare what the program does with what you expect. You should notice something interesting when you try to find the second-largest number.

Comment: `std::partial_sort(arr, arr + 3, arr + s, std::greater<>{});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that before iterating the loop, you first set the `maxValue` to be the first element in the array. The `imax` only gets updated whenever there is at least one element greater than the current `maxValue`. However, if the first element is somehow the `maxValue` you are looking for, then the `imax` never gets set, which would be uninitialized causing segmentation fault at the end.

In your code, after finding the largest element 545, the second largest element was never found, since 121 is the first element in the array. Hence after printing out 545, `imax[1]` is uninitialized and the program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You use uninitialized array values in lines

```
cout<<"First biggest number:"<<arr[imax[0]]<<"\n";
cout<<"Second biggest number:"<<arr[imax[1]]<<"\n";
cout<<"Third biggest number:"<<arr[imax[2]];
```

If there are **less than 3 different** numbers in input, some `imax` array elements will not be initialized. Also if input array is empty, imax will not be initialized at all.

Therefore in expression `arr[imax[1]]` you read element of `arr` with index, which was not initialized and can be some very big number. It can be fixed if you declare `iarr` as

```
int imax[t] = {};
```

This will zero-initialize all elements of array and will prevent crashing.

Your program also doesn't check number of elements in input array, so if there are less than three input numbers `arr[2]` will also print uninitialized value.

Here's proper solution using STL algorithms and std::vector. It works with any number of `t` - you can easily change it to print largest 10 numbers. It is also memory efficient - it does not need to store whole input array so you can process large inputs with it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int s;
  std::cin >> s;

  unsigned t = 3;
  std::vector<int> max_numbers;
  max_numbers.reserve(t + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
    int number;
    if (std::cin >> number) { //Check basic input errors
      max_numbers.push_back(number); // Add number to top-3 list

      // Sort elements in descending order
      std::sort(max_numbers.begin(), max_numbers.end(), std::greater<int>());

      // Remove duplicates
      max_numbers.erase(std::unique(max_numbers.begin(), max_numbers.end()),
                        max_numbers.end());

      // Remove excess elements
      if (max_numbers.size() > t) {
        max_numbers.resize(t);
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Biggest " << t << " numbers are" << std::endl;
  for (int i : max_numbers) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```